# JIRA: Issue classification, clarification needed

Tags: agile, jira

In JIRA, when creating a new issue, i am presented with a number of choices, some of which look like they don't belong.

For example:

"New Feature". This should be a part of a story right? How can one chose when to use "New Feature" and when to use a "Story"?

"New Feature" looks like a type to me or a "Story" to me.

Or, take for instance "Improvement". We can start a whole project with it's own "Epic" for the sole purpose to improve a bunch of things. Should such work be filed under an "Epic" or under something else?

Please clarify

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for help with a specific software tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JIRA is a generic issue tracking system. It presents you with a number of pre-configured options which are thought to be useful to the majority of users as they start out.

Every team that uses agile methods needs to come to its own definition of what exactly a "Story" is or an "Epic", and whether or not "Story" and "New Feature" are equivalent. Once you have settled on these internal definitions, you need to go and either customize JIRA so that it fits your process, or make some kind of mapping between the two.

For what it's worth, my own definition for these items is: An Epic consists of one or more Features, and each Feature consists of one or more Stories. And Improvement would possibly be either a single story, but it could span multiple stories (for big improvements) or one story could be collection of a lot of minor improvements (sometimes also called tweaks). But, as said, you need to arrive at your own definition of what exactly these words mean in your team.

Comment: Just found this, and wanted to add that this doesn't really fit with Greenhopper (the Agile add-on for Jira), but works in core Jira using Issue Linking (I'm assuming). To use it in Greenhopper, you don't have the ability to link as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A Jira Kanban Project (out of the box) displays a field called "Epic Link" in each Story, Feature, Task, Defect or several other issue types.
This is true of the both server and cloud versions.

This lends itself to using Epic to mean a collection of stories. Stories and Features can also have sub-tasks assigned. Storys usually give some business value while Tasks do not. It is not clear how a Feature differs from a Story as they have similar behaviour.

Storys hav no field called "Feature Link", but your admin could configure one if you wished to group stories to Features.
Nor are there sub-tasks.

The [Structure Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure) (on the server edition) may allow more levels.

Comment: Recommended reading: **[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/439793)**